# Count the length of elements inside a parent div and put a specific class name according number of childs

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, switch-statement

I've tried to run an "if" function to add "singleElement" or "multiElement" classes according the number of elements inside to the parent div ("panelContainer"), but the funcion insert the same class to all the parent divs and doesn't count the elements inside to put the according class.

If I execute the "alert(ne)" function it returns separate alerts with the number of "child elements" inside each parent div ("panelContainer"), but the if function doesn't works fine.

What's wrong with my code?

```
  $('.panelContainer').each(function() {
       var thispanel = $(this);
       var ne = $(thispanel).children('.ReservationMainPanel').length;
       alert(ne);

             if($(ne).length >1){
             $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');

              }
              else{
               $(thispanel).addClass('multiElement');
             }  

      });
```

And try with "case" and the same issue, put the same class to all the parent divs in the DOM.

```
      switch (ne) {
        case (ne >= 2):
            $(thispanel).addClass('multiElement');

            break;

        case (ne === 1):
            $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');

            break;

        default:
            $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');
            break;
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Idk when your code is executed, but you might wanna make sure it's executed after everything has louded and been mounted to the DOM. Make use `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your `switch` statement.

```
switch (ne) {
    case (ne >= 2):
        $(thispanel).addClass('multiElement');

        break;

    case (ne === 1):
        $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');

        break;

    default:
        $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');
        break;
}
```

For your cases, you only need to put the value of the `variable` that is the target of your `switch` statement. A `switch` statement should not be treated like a series of `if`s and `else if`s. If you want to use a `switch` statement like a series of `if` and `else if` statements, you can use `switch(true)`:

```
switch (true) {
    case (ne >= 2):
        $(thispanel).addClass('multiElement');

        break;

    case (ne === 1):
        $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');

        break;

    default:
        $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');
        break;
}
```

Your `if else` statement also has a few problems.

```
   if($(ne).length >1){
         $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');

          }
          else{
           $(thispanel).addClass('multiElement');
         }
```

As `ne` is already a Number, you only need to check if it is more than 1, not if its length is more than one. As well, you do not need to wrap it with `$()`.

```
   if(ne >1){
         $(thispanel).addClass('singleElement');

          }
          else{
           $(thispanel).addClass('multiElement');
         }
```

Demo:

```css
.panelContainer{
  background-color: #fef;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.singleElement{
  background-color: #ffff4d;
}

.multiElement{
  background-color: #4dff4d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panelContainer"></div>
<div class="panelContainer"><span>One child</span></div>
<div class="panelContainer"><span>Child One</span><span>Child Two</span></div>
<script>
$('.panelContainer').each(function() {
       var thispanel = $(this);
       var ne =  thispanel.children().length;
       alert(ne);
       if(ne>=1){//at least one child
        thispanel.addClass('multiElement');
       } else {//no children
         thispanel.addClass('singleElement');
       }
});
</script>
```

You can use `$('#parent *').length` which gets the number of all children (not necessarily direct children) of the `#parent` element (unlike jQuery's `.children()` function which only gets the number of direct children).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"><!--parent-->
<textarea></textarea><!--1 element-->
<span>Layer 1 <span>Nested Layer 2 <span>Nested Layer 3</span></span></span><!--3 elements here-->
</div>
<script>
var numOfChildren = $('#parent *').length;
console.log(numOfChildren);
</script>
```

You can achieve this in plain Javascript using `document.querySelectorAll('#parent *').length`.

```html
<div id="parent"><!--parent-->
    <textarea></textarea><!--1 element-->
    <span>Layer 1 <span>Nested Layer 2 <span>Nested Layer 3</span></span></span><!--3 elements here-->
</div>
<script>
var numOfChildren = document.querySelectorAll('#parent *').length;
console.log(numOfChildren);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed the issue with your example :)

Comment: @AlonsoCT No problem.

Comment: `$('.panelContainer').each(function() {
       var thispanel = $(this);
       var numOfChildren =  thispanel.children().length;
       //alert(ne);
       if(numOfChildren<=1){
        thispanel.addClass('singleElement');
       } else {
         thispanel.addClass('multiElement');
        }
     });`

Answer (score -1):

"ne" is already an int, so this line is causing your code to not work properly:

```
if($(ne).length >1)
```

Example:

```
$(1).length // returns 1
$(2).length // returns 1
$(99).length // returns 1
```

You can simply use `if(ne == 1)`